# Use query value on where clause

Tags: prisma

i`m trying to do the following query:

```
findMany({
      where: {
        worker_id: 1,
        AND: [
          {
            facility: {
              is_active: true,
            },
          },
          {
            is_deleted: false,
            worker_id: null,
          },
          {
            worker: {
              is_active: true,
            },
          },
          {
            profession: worker.profession,
          },
        ],
      },
    });
```

Where worker.profession would be the selected field, something similar on doing this manually.

```
SELECT worker.profession from worker INNER JOIN shift .... WHERE shift.profession = worker.profession
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment (2024.03.21) prism does not support such operations. There is only support for [comparing columns in the same table](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/reference/prisma-client-reference#compare-columns-in-the-same-table).
[Here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/15068) you can find a discussion of a similar feature on github, but alas, the full fieldReference functionality has not been implemented yet(